# Analyze critical points of $ f (x, y) = 3(x^2 + y^2) - 2 (x^3 - y^3) + 6xy \quad (x, y) \in R $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We are supposed to analyze following function in terms to classify it critical points.

$F(x,y) = 3(x^2 + y^2) - 2 (x^3 - y^3) + 6xy \quad (x, y) \in R$

The obvious critical point (0,0) turns to be doubtful case.
We could rewrite fxn as $3 (x + y)^2 - 2(x^3-y^3) $

But how to confirm from here whether this point is maxima, minima, or saddle?

Comment: please read the following: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test

Comment: @AnuragA i have already computed det of hessian matrix, its the doubtful case

Answer (score 0):

Plot the function around $(0,0)$ and notice that the graph looks like a  chair.

[image]

Indeed, we have $f(t,t) = 12t^2$ while $f(t,-t) = - 4 t^3$.

The singular point $(0,0)$ is degenerate. The second derivative test at $(0,0)$ is a priori inconclusive.

However, from the analysis above we conclude that $(0,0)$ is neither a saddle nor a local extremum.

Note that we can get even more info by restricting the function $f$ to all the lines passing through $(0,0)$.

Comment: How to do it without plotting graph?

Comment: We restrict to the two lines through the origin like above. It solves this problem. The graph helps with the intuition, it's not required.

Comment: I was trying to complete square in f ,but it didnot seem to help ,

Comment: @ketan: The function is similar to the function $g(u,v)=u^2 + v^3$. Think of it: does $g$ have a local minimum, a local maximum or a saddle point at zero? No, rather a (beach) chair. The Hessian matrix at $(0,0)$ is degenerate, so the usual theorem cannot decide, basically it tell you to further analyze.

Comment: @ketan: Completing the square is a good start. There is a change of coordinates that will reduce it to $u^2 + v^3$, however it may require a non-linear change of coordinates to also get a cube.